# Serial program not responding on boot

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to run a program written in C that uses ttyX for serial communication. The program is running on Cubieboard2 with Debian OS. When I run the program manually, it successfully runs and responds to data fed in ttyX by some external device. BUT when I add this program to run at boot time, it runs but does not responds to commands on ttyX sent by external device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem with the boot order? It sounds like the program starts too early.

Comment: Then shouldnt it give error while opening port?

Comment: Added my process to S99 in rcX.d directories, still no luck..

Comment: The problem was on coding side. The issue has been resolved and can be seen at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665920/serial-port-not-responding-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment43758919_27665920